# How do I use neo4j Relationship types in a switch statement?

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement, neo4j

In ReqsDb.java I have:

```
public static enum RelTypes implements RelationshipType {
    IDENTIFIES, IS_MEMBER
}
```

In another class I have:

```
ReqsDb reqsDb = new ReqsDb();

for (Relationship rel : reqsDb.getAllRelationships()) {
    switch (rel.getType()) {
        case reqsDb.RelTypes.IDENTIFIES:
            doStuff();
        case reqsDb.RelTypes.IS_MEMBER:
            doOtherStuff();
    }
}
```

However, the compiler is complaining about incompatible types and claims that

```
reqsDb.RelTypes.IDENTIFIES
```

is not a constant expression.

Is it not possible to use enum implements RelationshipType in a switch statement or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You can try to do: `switch(reqsDb.RelTypes.valueOf(rel.getType().getName())`

Comment: RelationshipType does not have such a method that I'm aware of. There is RelationshipType.name() but it returns a string... no good for switch statements in the version im using.

Comment: I'm not married to the switch statement, in fact I've moved on using if statements. But are you aware of a standard approach to getting behavior based on RelationshipType?